# How to click browser refresh confirmation pop up when testing with selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have an issue when trying to test a web application with Selenium IDE when i refresh the web page a browser confirmation message is pop upped, is there any option in selenium IDE to automatically click ok to this browser confirmation message

please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

Dismissing alert/prompt/confirmation dialogs launched from an onload event is a long-standing issue with Selenium, and nobody has been able to find a way to do it.  Selenium handles these dialogs at all other times just fine, but during page load it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Have u used assertConfirmation ? If not try it. I have used it to handle such confirmations.

Comment: But friend ,its not working for browser refresh  confirmation message.